# Sendmail works in perl but not in CRON

Tags: perl, cron, sendmail

I have a perl script that is executed by a cron job.  At the end of the script it sends out an email to let me know it finished.  When I run the script through the command line it runs fine.  When I run it through the cron, everything works, except I never get the email.  I'm using SENDMAIL to send the email.  I have no root access.  I am a standard user.  Any thoughts?

Here is the part of the script that I use for the SENDMAIL.

```
my $sendmail = "/usr/lib/sendmail -t";
my $to = "To: ". "me\@test.com\n";
my $from     = "From: SUCCESS\@test.com\n";
my $reply_to = "Reply-to: me\@test.com\n";
my $content = "Updated the File\n";
my $subject = "Subject: SUCCESS \n";
my $cc = "";

open(SENDMAIL, "|$sendmail") or die "Cannot open $sendmail: $!";
print SENDMAIL $to;
print SENDMAIL $cc;
print SENDMAIL $from;
print SENDMAIL $reply_to;
print SENDMAIL $subject;
print SENDMAIL "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print SENDMAIL $content;
close(SENDMAIL);
```

Comment: Set `MAILTO` in your crontab instead, your script doesn't need to know how to send mail.

Answer (score 0):

Is the path to sendmail correct? Cron is not aware of your environment, try using the full path. In Ubuntu it would be '/usr/sbin/sendmail', obviously it may differ dependent on your distro.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the answer.  It turns out the script wasn't working because the CRON uses a different file path than the script when you run it normally.

What really helped was running mail and seeing all of the error messages the CRON had sent to my account.  Ah the joys of being a N00b.